# How do I render the count of multiple rows in Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Input data:

| Location |
| --- |
| europe_w |
| asia_s |
| us_e |
| asia_e |
| us_w |
| us_c |
| asia_c |

I want this result using a Kusto query in Azure Data Explorer:

| Location | Count |
| --- | --- |
| asia | 3 |
| europe | 1 |
| us | 3 |

Can't seem to figure out how to count by a specific substring and output it as a new value showing the total count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
datatable(Location:string)
[
'europe_w',
'asia_s',
'us_e',
'asia_e',
'us_w',
'us_c',
'asia_c'
]
| extend Region = substring(Location,0,indexof(Location,"_"))
| summarize Count = count() by Region
```

In this query,  `extend`  operator is used to extract the substring before the first underscore character (`_`) in the  `Location`  column to create a new column  `Region`.  `substring`  function  extracts the substring before the first underscore character. Finally, to count the occurrences of each  `Region`  `summarize` operator is used.

The output of this query:

| Region | Count |
| --- | --- |
| europe | 1 |
| asia | 3 |
| us | 3 |

You can also use the below code.

```
datatable(Location:string)
[
    'europe_w',
    'asia_s',
    'us_e',
    'asia_e',
    'us_w',
    'us_c',
    'asia_c'
]
|summarize count() by tostring(split(Location, "_")[0])
```

This query gives the same expected result.

Edit:

> how would you do if the input data was like this: europew, asias, use, asiae, usw, usc, asiac (no specific char that separates the string)?

```
datatable(Location:string)
[
  'europe_w',
  'asia_s',
  'us_e',
  'asia_e',
  'us_w',
  'us_c',
  'asia_c'
]
| extend Region = case(
    Location contains "europe", "europe",
    Location contains "asia", "asia",
    Location contains "us", "us",
    "unknown"
  )
| summarize Count = count() by Region
| where Region != "unknown"
```

This query uses the `case()` function to create a new column called `Region` that maps each location to its corresponding region. If the `Location` column contains the string `europe`, the `Region` column will be set to `europe`. If it contains the string `asia`, the `Region` column will be set to `asia`. If it contains the string `us`, the `Region` column will be set to `us`. You can extend this if you have multiple base locations. If it does not contain any of these strings, the `Region` column will be set to `unknown`.

Comment: how would you do if the input data was like this: europew, asias, use, asiae, usw, usc, asiac (no specific char that separates the string)?

Comment: Edited the answer . Check that